# VS2015 stops debugger after iOS app is launched

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

VS2015 stops debugger after iOS app is launched and i am getting error in console

Launching 'Sample.iOS' on 'I phone 4s'...
The app has been terminated.

Comment: You have to fix the error which you are getting in console.

Comment: How can i fix the error .

Comment: You have to show us the error which you are getting in Console

Comment: Launching 'Sample.iOS' on 'I phone 4s'... The app has been terminated. this is displaying in Debug console

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when your app crashes. Your application code is crashing the app at runtime. You could check the iOS device log to figure out the problem.

Also, I found that adding a winphone or UWP project to a xamarin project helps you debug. The errormessages windows devices give are a bit more descriptive.

Comment: App is not crashed.App is succesfully launched and then app is going to terminated .not going to debug.this is not happen in iOS Simulator.

Comment: Does your app still run after it says terminated?

Comment: Yes it is running after termination also.